# std::async with std::unique doesn't compile

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <future>

using namespace std;

unique_ptr<int> uq(new int);

void foo(unique_ptr<int> q)
{}

int main()
{
    foo(move(uq));
    // ^ OK

    async(foo, move(uq));
    // ^ Error: error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr' :
    //    cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'
}
```

Why 'async' doesn't compile? I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 (v4.5.50709).

Comment: `...` as a standalone statement is not valid C++, and you're missing some `#include`s.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit
I just don't want to repeat the everyone-known codes.

Comment: Your idea of what "everyone knows" is subjective and may contain errors. Best to leave off the `...` entirely, and write the proper `#include`s so that we can see that _you_ know it properly. After all, that's why you came here, right?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit As you wish, here is including: `#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <future>
using namespace std;
`

Comment: Thanks; I have edited this detail into your question for you, to create a [testcase](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 2):

This should work according to the standard and it [does work on gcc](http://ideone.com/QM9RtB).

The reason it fails on VS is probably because `std::async` is allowed to store internal copies of its arguments, which will then get passed on to the called function at a later point.

In this case, that would require *two* moves on the unique_ptr: One to construct the intermediate object for async and then a second one when passing the argument on to `foo`. One of the two probably fails. The Standard however explicitly states that the arguments to `async` must only be MoveConstructible (§ 30.6.8.2), which `unique_ptr` is.

So I would say this is a bug in VS2012's implementation of the standard library.

Comment: I even can NOT compile it on gcc 4.7.2.